# Should Stack Overflow block access from Russian IP addresses?

Tags: discussion

Should Stack Overflow block access from Russian IP addresses?

Or at least show some kind of a click-through about the war and condemnation of Russian government before allowing access.

Comment: No. See this MSE post: [Is SE going to limit Russia-based individuals and companies' access to its resources?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376642)

Comment: At least to raise awareness of the problem in Russian society, as with state-controlled media, they don't even know that they are in a war.

Comment: Why do you think they don't know they are in war? Also how would restricting access to outside world help those people getting more information besides those provided by state controlled media?

Comment: There are far better ways to raise awareness to others, in and outside of Russia, than banning Russian users from sites like [main].

Comment: Why do you think they know what is happening besides some rumors? How exactly? From TV? "What war, there's no war, the word "war" is banned, casualties, nah, your son had an accident"… From western news sites? Blocked. From Wikipedia? A click-through about the war and condemnation of Russia government would not ban them, but maybe cause them to seek more information. It's not less important than warning them about cookies…

Comment: i really can't understand what your problem is, every day people die wih gun hsot wounds. every year the are 250 military and armed conflict. Onöly difference is, nobody gives a penny or reaches media hype.

Comment: Me stupid. I didn't know every day foreign countries invade other countries using thousands of armored vehicles, hundreds or war planes and cruise missiles and hundreds of thousands of personnel, causing thousands of casualties and destroyed equipment from both sides. Day like every day, indeed…

Comment: Have you been living under the rock or you just prefer to be blind to wars caused by the West?

Comment: For one thing, I have lived through one war in the '90s even though it happened before the Internet as we know it today, so I know something about it. People on the other side are aware what is happening. People on all sides know something is going on, and access to different information is crucial to getting the whole picture. Also sanctions and isolation don't help much as they mostly hurt and impact little people that are already suffering. Causing them to suffer more is not actually improving the situation in any way.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know Putin had an account here! That is pretty awesome. I'm sure he will be devastated when he can no longer enjoy new PHP questions ....

Answer (score 1):

No. I think we need to distinguish between Stack Overflow and the community. There is no reason to self-punish the community as long as we can't say that the specific user had a negative impact on this conflict (in this situation SO should punish this specific user if the SO was used by this user in this conflict context).

However, if you are asking as well about if SO should do something, then yes, I think as long as SO can't be sure that their businees had negative impact on this conflict, they should at least show that they are aware of the situation and perhaps even propose something specific what they could do.

We are all here well aware that the code published in SO could be used in the agressive context in this war. But that's only the one side - it is rather the matter of "being morally aware of this" then "being morally obligated to do something".

On the other side we need to remember that SO *perhaps* (as there wasn't any official statement about this) keeps continue business as usual, I mean they are making money because of ads or jobs with the organization in the Russian territory. SO helps them grow, these organizations pays taxes and now the money from taxes is used in this war. A lot of companies decided to stop trading with Russia *because of this*.

However, if this sound too controversial (and I could agree), we can imagine another proposition: SO can do something using the money they receives from organization from Russian territory (the money which left for SO after they pay employees etc.). I think this is what should they do.