# Does Stack Overflow have moral obligation to do something regarding the war between Russia and Ukraine?

Tags: discussion, ethics

**Official statement posted by SE**

[Stack Exchange Q&A access will not be restricted in Russia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376743/stack-exchange-qa-access-will-not-be-restricted-in-russia)

---

Possibly duplicated with: [Is SE going to limit Russia-based individuals and companies' access to its resources?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376642/is-se-going-to-limit-russia-based-individuals-and-companies-access-to-its-resou), because this question: [Should Stack Overflow block access from Russian IP addresses?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416240/should-stack-overflow-block-access-from-russian-ip-addresses?noredirect=1&lq=1) is possibly duplicated with the question on Meta SE (according to first comment in which I agree). Sorry, I have missed this!

**Context:**

**(1)**

Russian soldiers are killing people in Ukraine. Both soldiers and civilians, including children.

**(2)**

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the place where developers learn and build careers (taking from the self-description of the website). In the [2021 Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#key-territories-all-countries) Russian Federation was in 13th place in the survey responses (however, it doesn't mean Russian Federation is in 13th place in terms of the number of users on Stack Overflow).

Stack Overflow is used for asking questions about the programming. The questions exist in a non-political context, i.e. it is not possible to say if the code will be used to solve a problem with a medical program or for developing a combat drone or to shut down Ukrainian websites.

Stack Overflow hasn't done anything regarding the war (including releasing any statement) and has not publicly said that they did something. It could mean that this situation has no impact on their revenue, i.e. **nothing has changed regarding making money in the Russian Federation area, like the money from [ads or jobs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/15/how-we-make-money-at-stack-overflow-2016-edition/). This helps organizations in Russia grow, so they can pay taxes and this money can be then be used to kill people**.

**My Question:**

Does Stack Overflow have a moral obligation to do or say something to show that they are aware of the situation in Ukraine? Because their business could have a direct *military* impact on the people in Ukraine because without a line of code the weapon won't work, but it is impossible to say if the line of code was taken from Stack Overflow.

Should they do something more than just publish a statement, i.e. should they do something which will have a direct impact on the people in Ukraine?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried on Stackoverflow Meta 2 days ago with the proposition to close the Stack Overflow for Russians, but was closed as not related to Stack Overflow (which I don't agree with, but closed means "you can't speak anymore"). But on the other hand this question is asked in different way and is not so controversial I think (however something similar is on GitHub: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/12042, however I had also make different proposition in the meantime: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/12152)

Comment: @Robert Longson thank you, didn't see it. However, I see the post you send do not receives valuable input from community as moderators could say and my question is different - I don't propose anything specific. Hope community will be more open in this case.

Comment: Is Oberflow some attempt to insult Stack Overflow? Because if you hope to gather support by insulting the site, you just get the opposite.

Comment: Well, lacking an army, navy, air force and nuclear weapons, what do you suggest that a corporate entity armed with a database of software Q&A could do?  DDoS the tanks?

Comment: @MartinJames in theory, banning people from Russia from using Stack Overflow would hurt Russia, and might even have some impact.

Comment: @RobertLongson one time, sure. But it's more than one.

Comment: I have decided to highlight the part of my questions regarding "what SO can do and what happens when SO do nothing".

Comment: Always look on the bright side of life - if the fighting spills over into NATO countries and we all get sucked into WWIII, we won't have to deal with 'Homework Sunday' assignment dumps any more:)

Comment: I would like to very, very clearly point out that voting to close this question because of being opinion-based in unfair. The tag "ethics" is used for this kind of questions, like "whether it's OK to help someone create viruses, or pirate software". Also, this is not a question "generally, what should be done...", but "taking into account fact1, fact2 etc., does these facts make something morally obligatory?"

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron arguably, it'd mostly hurt the average person, and I'm sure the propaganda machine will find a way to frame it as the west being evil. The bulk of the sanctions so far have actively been targeting the government for a reason. Or, as many people have put it, Putin != Russia. There's also [lots of protests](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2022/02/25/russia-protests-war-ukraine-despite-risks/) already. I fail to see how cutting Russians out of SO (and other major dev sites) is going to do anything but provide more cannon fodder for Putin's propaganda machine

Comment: @Zoe don't get me wrong, I agree with you, but I also see the other side view. Those average people who will get hurt might go and protest, demanding their leaders to stop, so they can use SO again.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Hates Omicron You really belive in this? So you want people to be punished twice? Also Russia can now say, that the West, represented by you, is organising protests and interfering into internal afairs of Russia.

Comment: @convert like I said to Zoe, I'm not supporting this, but yes I do believe it can have some impact, that was my point. And the sanctions the West already put in place against Russia have great negative impact on innocent civilians already, so it's not really relevant.

Comment: I'll argue there's no way to really win here. The best SO can do is post a statement, and potentially send some financial support to Ukraine. But it's not like they have a couple hundred million they can send to Ukraine, and they're not exactly the type of organization that can just send some people to Poland or whatever to help with  the humanitarian side of things. Any blocks are gonna get converted to propaganda, and doing nothing, as evidenced by this question, gets perceived as ignoring it for money.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Hates Omicron It´s wired logic you have. What is the intention of such sanctions? Aslo there are russians outside Russia, how you want prevent them from using SO?

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine you could post this as an answer. Your comment received 4 likes, including from me, and I would be happy to see this as an answer, especially since this question is close to being closed because of opinion-based. Your answer show that it is possible to write a good answer which community agree with.

Comment: @gss Have read the thread from your link to github. The logic of that is in some way similar to the logic of islamists blowing up a synagoge because Israel is killing palestinians.

Comment: Vote to reopen. Have never understood the validity of the opinion-based close reason on meta. Half of the discussions here are opinion-based. This only looks like a try to stifle a discussion that some people don't like. It's much better to express disagreement in an answer instead.

Comment: For the record, [SO has now posted their stance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376743/332043).

Answer (score -22, accepted):

There is a moral obligation for everyone to do what they can to avoid bloodshed and aggression everywhere. Now Stack Overflow is a collaborative effort. It works best when it's completely apolitical, i.e. serves people everywhere equally. In that we should be fully aware that it can do both good and bad, please don't entertain any illusion there.

Example: Maybe Russian military attack systems were programmed with the help of knowledge from Stack Overflow and that might have increased their efficacy. Given the large amount of knowledge stored here and the large number of visits to Stack Overflow, that might even be very likely.

I don't know exactly what you have in mind, but if for example, Stack Overflow were to temporarily switch off its Russian language localized site or restrict access to the English main site based on geography, I would have some sympathies for that and would say we should discuss and consider it.

That would put Russia on one level as for example Iran, but well, I think that might be kind of appropriate.

Given that Stack Overflow Inc. is a private owned company, I do not think that to be very likely though. Morality for companies has yet to be developed.

On the other hand, Stack Overflow can hardly do something significant about wars. The software used now is already written. If you really want to do something, your countries' government is a much bigger factor. Petition to your government and use your political influence as citizen to make a small positive change in the world.

Comment: _"There is a moral obligation for everyone to do what they can to avoid bloodshed and aggression everywhere."_ Eh, no. For example, I have no obligation to intervene in any middle-eastern conflict. "Morality" rhetoric aside, all you're advocating for, is punishing the subjects of a crazy man.

Comment: More than >70% of "the subjects" support the "crazy man".

Comment: @Trilarion when it comes to domestic issues, the answer seems to be no https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384811

Comment: @user2284570 How do you know that? There is no answer yet to the question you link to.

Comment: @user2284570 a question being closed by the community isn't an indication of the company's stance.

Comment: @KevinB worst! It explains how the community or moderators would react to such content on the legal side.

Comment: @Trilarion content mad downvoted. Not only asking such content not allowed but talking about allowing it not allowed too,

Comment: @user2284570 i downvoted your question because it was unclear to me, as I indicated in the comments. That's how this site works. The question is still in a state that seems pretty useless to me, as it's not up to the community to decide what the company bans, and in legality cases such as the US banning something, that's more up to SO's lawyers than the SO team or the community.

Comment: Downvoting is for whatever reason i feel like clicking the downvote button for, realistically. But we prefer it be used to indicate usefulness and clarity, as indicated by the downvote tooltip and help articles. Do note that the tooltip is different for questions vs answers.

Comment: @KevinB you didn t told in the comment what was unclear for you (you didn t wrote a comment at all). Downvoting is for things not useful (since you disagree, please reread the question tooltip). Everything in the question is required to not be biased. And asking a question with the relevant staff tag is how stack exchange could clarify (except when it s closed).

Comment: @user2284570 "content mad downvoted." That can have different reasons. Don't judge content on meta by the score (alone). Just wait for answers. If the question remains open (and I voted for it) an answer might eventually come (or if not you also have kind of an answer). For example this answer here has a negative score but I don't mind. I still stand 100% behind it. In my eyes it's the right answer, regardless of what others think. Your question has 0 answers, so officially it's still open. However, I think the company doesn't care enough about your issue.

Answer (score 44):

I don't know how many downvotes this answer would collect, but allow me to show you the situation from the other side.

As you may have deduced, I am Russian. Although I am not pleased with this fact, I cannot do much about it. I did not vote for Putin, nor for his political party, and I do not approve what is happening right now. Some of my relatives live in Ukraine (in Lugansk, to be precise) and, as you can imagine, having a war conflict near their house goes strictly against my interests. And my situation is not uncommon, many other Russians have relatives and/or friends on the other side, this is just a legacy of the Soviet Union.

It may come as a surprise, but a large group of locals actually cheer sanctions if they are directed at the ruling party. Hell, some even tried to propose new ones. The government responded with a law, clarifying such actions as a crime. However, this particular proposal won't hurt the right people in the slightest, not mentioning that IP address filters are fairly useless in case of Russia. Our government has an infamous habit to block unwanted websites, so even the people who are not familiar with computer science do know how to use VPN or TOR to bypass restrictions.

So the only people who would get affected are the SO contributors, like myself. And what have I done to deserve such treatment? I heard many thanks said to me on this website and it is extremely frustrating to face the fact that in one day I have become a villain in public opinion, just because I live in this country.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your voice. I would like to say that I'm against closing SO for Russians. I just can't understand how SO cannot even make a statement about all of this.

Comment: @gss Oh, I must have misread your intentions with all the sudden hatred I see everywhere. I beg your pardon.

Comment: @gss Stack Overflow is _not_ a political platform. That's why.

Comment: @Cebrus nice argument. You can say this Ukrainians, for example: "Do you want to go shop and can't? Just say 'this is not a political shopping!'.

Comment: Oh, that "political shopping" again, @gss... That's not even close to being the same. You're comparing __physical danger__ to political statements. There's nothing political about buying a carton of eggs. They may not be able to because of the war, but that doesn't mean buying eggs is an anti-<country> statement.

Comment: If you're unwilling to discuss this with me, then I suggest you don't reply to me, @gss. I'm free to answer you, if you reply to me.

Comment: @Cerbrus to be honest, I could discuss with you, but the problem is that you have much more power than I and you showing this very often sinve 2 days. This is not equal situation.

Comment: What privileges I have earned on SO is pretty irrelevant to us having a discussion about SO not being the place for political statements.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are closing or hiding the questions without the good reasons. But you also don't understand that answers should be post as answers, not in comments. If you want to say that SO should do nothing because it in not a political place, you can do this by posting an answer.

Comment: My actions here have good reasons, and most of them require a community consensus (I'm not unilaterally deleting stuff)

Comment: Yes, you wrote that very clearly previously. But it doesn't mean this is true. It looks that your decisions are motivated only by your opinion regarding this topic.

Comment: @gss "*you are closing or hiding the questions without the good reasons.*" to be clear - Cerbrus cannot unilaterally delete posts. It takes *at least* three users to vote for deletion. Cerbrus is also unable to unilaterally close posts. It takes five users to vote for closure. Only diamond mods can do these actions with one vote. There is a special case for gold badge holders - they can close *as a duplicate* using a single vote. [Cerbrus has one in discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/discussion?userid=1835379). However, this hasn't been used recently.

Comment: @VLAZ thank you for answer. To be honest, I feel confused because I really do not feel that some actions performed here by some people are fair, but probably it is because of my mood. Sorry, Cerbrus.

Comment: To be fair, I _did_ gold-hammer a [duplicate discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416255) posted by gss, but that was asking the same thing as the previous question.

Comment: That's OK. It was justified.

Comment: It is easy to just put everyone in the same basket. After WW2 all Germans were nazis, at least in the public eye. During the pandemic people from China living overseas were suddenly all responsible for spreading the virus. You **have** to contain yourself, even in the worst of times. Keep thinking critically, not emotionally.

Comment: @Gimby You're right, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: I was going to ask this question, but this provided the answer I needed.  My apologies for your troubling situation, I wish you and your family the best, hopefully Putin will be stopped somehow. I do not fault you for his actions. @Gimby *especially* in the worst of times. People of Asian descent are still being attacked by total strangers, it's as pointless as it is horrible.

Comment: @anemyte I am kind of confused by how you phrase that response though, it's almost like I changed your mind about something? I 100% support your answer.

Comment: @Gimby Sorry for the confusion. There was no hidden meaning, and I truly appreciate the support. I had an intention to say more, but then I thought that would be the kind of an emotional response that you mentioned. I guess, I can say I contained myself this time :)

Comment: Thank-you for your insightful answer. From my vantage point, the vast majority of people don't view the war as 'Russia against Ukraine' but rather view the war as 'Putin against Humanity'.